# ScrollView slow on initial load #5069

Tags: android, scrollview, react-native

I have around 400 records that I want to display in a ScrollView.
Once the app starts, the issue is that it takes around 4 to 5 seconds in order for the data to appear.
After that, i can scroll as much as i want in a very smooth fashion.

What can i do to improve the initial display time?

Comment: use a `ListView` then

Comment: well, when i was implementing a `ListView`, i had a weird behaviour. The first 10 elements would be displayed and then the rest start to get dispalyed in a cinematic way. Also, i could now scroll the `ListView`

Comment: @pskink so i did try a `ListView` again and i still face that initial lag when loading. Should i play with some props like the `pageSize` or `initialListSize` ?

Comment: pageSize? initialListSize? what do you mean?

Comment: oh hold on. The `ListView` loads more rows on demand as the user scrolls?

Comment: `ListView` has an `Adapter` and shows as many items as is returned by adapter's `getCount` method, so if you return 400 in `getCount` then 400 items will be shown

Comment: Alright, thank you a lot for helping me figure it out. I wrote an answer accordingly. tl;dr use a listview :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so after having a chat with @pskink in the comments, I realised that the `ListView` is what I want to use.
This view will only display some rows, and then display more as the user scrolls.

If I want to set the initial row size however, I can do so by setting the `initialListSize` [prop](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#initiallistsize)

However, there's a known issue right now with the `ListView` that causes [the underlying ScrollView to scroll back up after a rapid scroll](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3042)